# ios SQLite - How do I set PRAGMA values?

Tags: ios, sqlite, pragma

I am using sqlite for ios database.
Recently I came up to "PRAGMA synchronous = OFF and PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY"
which will significantly improve the processing speed.
The question is, how do I apply these settings to iOS sqlite db?
Is there a way to inject these queries to the sqlite objects?
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: They improve the speed by introducing the chance of data corruption on any kind of crash. And you execute them like any other SQL statement.

Comment: So I just need to call it only once? Is it okay if I call it right before I create a table?

Comment: These settings do not apply to the database file but to the database connection.

Answer (score 0):

After you have opened your database simply execute a statement with the PRAGMA values in.

Like the following:

```
sqlite3_exec(dbHandle, "PRAGMA default_cache_size = 200; PRAGMA cache_size = 200;", 0, 0, 0);
```

This will remain in effect from then on.